# bulk update query for each record from output of select query in DB2

Tags: db2

I need to update a field CXDEMO present in the TEST table based on the output of the below select query for each record. The output of this query brings in 10000 records hence I would like to know whether there is a simply way to prepare an 10000 update queries for each record.

```
select A.item, B.description,A.id from TEST A 
left join TEST B on A.item=B.item and A.id <> B.id
where B.item is null
order by A.id, A.item
```

The output that should be something like below,

```
update TEST set CXDEMO='123' where item ='1000' and id='ROD'
update TEST set CXDEMO='123' where item = '1001' and id ='TABLE'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 'UPDATE TEST SET CXDEMO=''123'' WHERE ITEM=''' || A.item || ''' AND ID=''' || A.id || ''';'
from TEST A 
left join TEST B on A.item=B.item and A.id <> B.id
where B.item is null
order by A.id, A.item
```

Comment: I need individual update query and not a bulk update. I need to know whether there is a way to prepare update query dynamically for each record obtained in the select query